# How to add button to WYSIWYG to insert shortcode with params (filled in system popup)?

Tags: shortcode, tinymce, wysiwyg, plugin-tinymce

It seems to me that there must be a solution, but I haven't found it.
During the theme development process, we create many shortcodes for inserting unusual html layouts into the text.

It would be great to know a way how to add a button to the editor panel that would allow user to fill in the parameters and insert a shortcode into the text without having to “remember” its structure.

So let's say we have this sort of shortcode:

```
[shortcode_name attr1="" attr2="" attr3=""]TEXT[/shortcode]
```

And I want to add button to WYSIWYG, specify its icon and when user click it should show popup with three input fields for attr1-3.

Maybe someone has a ready-made code or knows a suitable plugin? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're describing the functionality of Shortcake: https://github.com/wp-shortcake/shortcake But these days if you have complex layout requirements that need a user-friendly UI you should really be using blocks: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/

Comment: @JacobPeattie wow, great! thanks for that! I will try to cope with it. Not so simple as I see, but anyway. Don't know why but clients usually hate Block Editor :( as other page builders 3rd party addons.